# Iterate through objects in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My PHP is receiving data like this:

```
[
    {
      "EMAIL": "hello@example.com",
      "GENDER": "Male"
    },
    {
      "EMAIL": "info@example.com",
      "GENDER": "Male"
    }
  ]
```

So, I then do something like this:

```
$entityBody=json_decode($data); //$data like the array above

foreach($entityBody as $value){
$email = $value->EMAIL;
//do something with $email
```

The problem is that the `foreach` only runs once and I can successfully process the email address in the first object. But the rest are ignored. So, in the case of the data above, I just get hello@example.com and nothing for info@example.com.

How do I need to adjust my `foreach`?

EDIT: Full code here following the janky way that Sendgrid requires you to send it.

```
foreach($entityBody as $value){
$array[0]['email'] = $value->EMAIL;

$data_json = json_encode($array);
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer XXXX";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients",

  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_json,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
if ($err) {

die();
}
else{//run good stuff
$new = json_decode( $response, true );
if($new['persisted_recipients'][0]!=""){

$submit = $new['persisted_recipients'][0];

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/".$listId."/"."recipients/".$submit,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,

));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;

die();
}
else{

 echo("success");
die();
}

}  
}
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($entityBody);` say before iterating over it? How is the data structure after decoding the JSON string?

Comment: Gee...thanks, @Martijn. Super helpful.

Comment: your loop not runs only once, you just re-assign `$email` value each time...

Comment: [The foreach will loop correctly](https://3v4l.org/qOKOc) as long as the invalid json is fixed

Comment: @ArtOsi How do I fix that?

Comment: You need to show us more of your code so we know what you're actually doing. The above snippet isn't enough for us to know where it fails (or even _how_ or _if_ it actually fails). Are you using `$email` inside or outside the loop, for example?

Comment: You can't have trailing commas in json

Comment: @jonmrich if you want to store all emails store them in array `$email[] =  $value->EMAIL;` but it is if you have correct json_decoded() result and can loop through it at first.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones That was just a typo in my copy paste.

Comment: @ArtOsi I don't want to store them. I want to run this "function" for each object in the array.

Comment: For clarity, this will correctly loop through your JSON and output each JSON object in the `foreach` loop. You'd replace the `print_r` with whatever you want to do with each object's data.  `<?php

$input = '[
 {
  "EMAIL": "hello@example.com",
  "GENDER": "Male"},
    {
  "EMAIL": "info@example.com",
  "GENDER": "Male"
 }
]';

$json = json_decode($input);

foreach($json as $j) {
 print_r($j);
}`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Added my full code to question.

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry...that was a typo.

Comment: based on your code, are you sure it's not hitting any of the `die()`s? That would stop execution and wouldn't continue looping.  If you strip out all the `curl` stuff, are you sure the `foreach` is the problem?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones That was it! Thanks. Had an extra `die()` in where I have the success. THANKS!

Comment: You should start by properly indent your code to make it more readable, easier to follow and easier to find mistakes.

Comment: `if ($err) {

die();
}` ? Without indicating what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

<s>**First**</s>

When using `json_decode`, the returned value is an associative array instead of an object.

Therefore, your code `$value->EMAIL` is invalid.

**Second**

The decoded JSON will become something like this:

```
[
    [
      "EMAIL" => "hello@example.com",
      "GENDER" => "Male"
    ],
    [
      "EMAIL" => "info@example.com",
      "GENDER" => "Male"
    ]
]
```

Therefore, in `foreach ($entityBody as $value)`, the `$value` points to an array instead of a value.

Hence, `$email = $value['EMAIL']` will fail too.

**Solution**

Use double `foreach`:

```
$data = '[
    {
        "EMAIL": "hello@example.com",
        "GENDER": "Male"
    },
    {
        "EMAIL": "info@example.com",
        "GENDER": "Male"
    }
]';

$entityBody = json_decode($data);

foreach ($entityBody as $value){

    // Remember $value === array
    foreach ($value as $key => $val){

        // You can process your data here
        if ($key === 'EMAIL')
            echo "Email: {$val}<br>";
        else if ($key === 'GENDER')
            echo "Gender: {$val}<br>";

    }

}
```

You can run the above code by copy-pasting it in [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

**EDIT**

[Apparently `json_decode` returns object for `{...}` data format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

So you can use the following code:

```
foreach ($entityBody as $value){
    $email = isset($value->EMAIL) ? $value->EMAIL : false;
    $gender = isset($value->GENDER) ? $value->GENDER : false;
}
```

Which makes your code perfectly fine.

I think what makes your code only run once is that, in the 2nd iteration of `foreach`, the value `$value->EMAIL` is not found, therefore throwing error and break out of execution.

**Solution** is to first check the data using `isset()`.

Comment: the second loop adds unnecessary complexity, the `EMAIL` can be accessed in the outer loop by directly accessing its key `$email = $value['EMAIL'];` and a simple `if(isset($value['EMAIL']))` will prevent undefined variable exceptions

Comment: @WilliamPerron well, well, how did I miss that. Thanks for pointing out.